# Booting into Windows 7 after installing Windows XP in dual boot

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, multi-boot

I had a Windows 7 only system with a C: and D: partition. Windows 7 was on  C: and no OS was on D:.

I then installed Windows XP in D:. Now when I boot my computer I go directly in Windows XP. How do I instead get a OS boot menu to show up at boot time from which I can choose which OS to boot from?

Answer (score 6):

Stick in your Windows 7 disk and after choosing regional settings, click "Repair my computer".

From here, click "startup repair".

This option should recreate the Windows 7 bootloader/options for you.

Comment: How to doing it manually?