# Windows 7 boot option missing after installing Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, multi-boot

I had a computer running on Windows 7 Pro. However, when I reinstalled Windows XP on the other partition and rebooted, only Windows XP loaded and booted and the Windows 7 boot option was missing.

How can I have a multi-boot option for Windows 7 and Windows XP?

Comment: Check out this link, http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/8057-dual-boot-installation-windows-7-xp.html

Answer (score 2):

Use the Windows 7 installation disk recovery utility to recover win7 boot. It will also add a Windows xp boot option. Alternatively use easybcd freeware from Windows xp to add Windows 7 boot loader and options.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/8057-dual-boot-installation-windows-7-xp.html) is a good guide to dualbooting XP and 7. Basically, when you installed XP, it wiped out your Windows 7 bootloader and you need to repair it. Here are the relevant sections:

---

```
7. In XP, download and install .Net Framework 2.0 (32-bit) version or .Net Framework 2.0 (64-bit) version first, and EasyBCD (free version) for your 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x86) XP.
NOTE: In XP, Net Framework is required to be installed to run EasyBCD. After you click on Register (at bottom of link) for the free EasyBCD, registration is not required to download it.

8. Run EasyBCD (free version).
NOTE: This is required to repair the Windows 7 boot file and add XP to the Windows Boot Manager list.

9. On the left side of EasyBCD, click on the Add New Entry button.

    A) In the top section under Operating Systems, click on the Windows tab.

    B) To the right of Type, select Windows NT/2k/XP/2k3 from the drop down menu.
    WARNING: Be sure to leave the Automatically detect correct drive box checked.

    C) To the right of Name, you can leave the default Microsoft Windows XP as the name to be displayed in the Windows Boot Manager, or you can type whatever name you would like to have instead.

    D) Click on the Add Entry button.

10. On the left side of EasyBCD, click on the BCD Deployment button, select (dot) the Install the Windows Vista/7 bootloader to the MBR option, and click on the Write MBR button.

11. Close EasyBCD.

12. Restart the computer to have the option to boot from Microsoft Windows XP or Windows 7.
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Download and install [Visual BCD](http://www.boyans.net)

1. Run Dual-boot Repair tool. Click "Automatic Repair".
2. Reboot - Win 7 will be default.
3. In Windows 7 install again Visual BCD.
4. Run Visual BCD Editor - right click and select "Create missing Windows loaders".

After reboot you will have a dual-boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

To re-instate the dual boot option of the Windows loader screen, the *simplest* option (without having to download any *additional* software) is, as [Giorgos Papadakis states above](https://superuser.com/questions/525486/windows-7-boot-option-missing-after-installing-windows-xp#answer-525489), to just use the Windows & install disk.

Following the process stated in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/296222/booting-into-windows-7-after-installing-windows-xp-in-dual-boot#answer-296225) to [Booting into Windows 7 after installing Windows XP in dual boot](https://superuser.com/questions/296222/booting-into-windows-7-after-installing-windows-xp-in-dual-boot):

> Stick in your Windows 7 disk and after choosing regional settings, click "Repair my computer".
>
> From here, click "startup repair".
>
> This option should recreate the Windows 7 bootloader/options for you.